# Save a new dataframe for every iteration of for loop

Tags: python, pandas

Im using a for loop to create several pd.Dataframes, but I cannot figure out how to save each one individually, for each loop. The provided code is just the bare minimum of what I did, but I think its enough to get the question. I want to save a dataframe for each direction individually. So far I always got stuck with the last one, while the others were lost. All items of the list "directions" are dataframes of their own.

I tried counting each iteration step and add a +1 to the dataframe name but it didnt work out as planned. Ideal would be to add the name of the direction (N, NE, etc...)

Here is how far I got now, with a little bit more of code:

```py
turbine         = pd.read_csv('testdaten.csv', sep=';')
turbine.columns = ['time', 'speed_turbine', 'degree_turbine', 'direction_turbine']
Emden           = pd.read_csv('rose.csv', sep=';')
Emden.columns   = ['time', 'speed_data', 'degree_data', 'direction_data']

N               = Emden.loc[(Emden['direction_data'] == 'N')]
NE              = Emden.loc[(Emden['direction_data'] == 'NE')]  
E               = Emden.loc[(Emden['direction_data'] == 'E')]
SE              = Emden.loc[(Emden['direction_data'] == 'SE')]
S               = Emden.loc[(Emden['direction_data'] == 'S')]
SW              = Emden.loc[(Emden['direction_data'] == 'SW')]
W               = Emden.loc[(Emden['direction_data'] == 'W')]
NW              = Emden.loc[(Emden['direction_data'] == 'NW')]

directions = [N, NE, E, SE, S, SW, W, NW]
locations  = [turbine]
merges = []
curves = []

for location in locations:
    d={'df_'+location: pd.merge(location, direction, on=['time'], how=['inner'])for direction in directions}

x=0
y=0.5
for Turbine in d:

    while x <= Turbine['speed_data'].max():
        sub = Turbine.loc[(Turbine['speed_data'] > x)&(Turbine['speed_data'] <= y)]  # filter the dataframe on both conditions
        Turbine.loc[sub.index, str(y)] = Turbine['speed_data']/Turbine['speed_turbine']
        x += .5
        y += .5


    Turbine.loc['Mean_Values'] = Turbine.mean(1)

    curves.append(Turbine)
```

Im getting the error that a list is not hashable.

Comment: Try this `'df_{}'.format(i)` instead of `df_+i`

Comment: Store them in a dictionary: `all_dataframes = {}` then inside your `for` loop: `all_dataframes[direction] = pd.merge ...`

Comment: `df_+i` is incorrect syntax in python: `a = pd.DataFrame(data={'x':[0,1,2]}); b = pd.DataFrame(data={'x':[0,1,2]}); a+3 = b` gives _"SyntaxError: can't assign to operator"_. You can not create a new variable name by just adding an integer to it. `a+3` is a DataFrame with all elements incremented by 3.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
directions = [N, NE, E, SE, S, SW, W, NE]
dfs = []

for direction in directions:
    dfs.append(pd.merge(location, direction, on=['time'], how=['inner']))
```

you have to create a list of dataframes

Comment: So if anybody cares, the error came up because how needs to be ='inner' instead of ['inner']...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [map](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-map-function/)

```
df = dict(map(lambda direction: (direction, pd.merge(location, direction, on=['time'], how=['inner'])), directions))
```

This will create a dictionary with (key, value) pair where key will be directions and value will be DataFrame